# как сделать доступ ко всем сайтам на 2 серверах под 1 внешним ip?

Tags: веб-программирование, nginx, ip, apache2

Есть 2 сервера:

> - у одного eth0 eth1 на eth0 внешний адрес 1.2.3.4  eth1 внутренний 192.168.1.1
> - у второго eth0 192.168.1.2

На обоих установлен **apache2**
Все сайты прописаны в днс на этот внешний ip. 
На первом сервере где внешний IP крутится 5 сайтов 
На втором сервере 1 сайт в дефолте.
Как показать все сайты в интернете? Возможно поставить **nginx** или есть другие варианты?

Comment: Один из простых вариантов - поднять на первом прокси - и заходить на сайты через прокси.

Comment: можно подробней?

Answer (score 2):

Nginx поставить - хороший вариант. Получите заодно и плюшки в виде более быстрой обработки статики.
В nginx'е для ваших целей нужно будет использовать директиву proxy_pass, которая скажет куда нужно перенаправить запрос. Будет это примерно так:

```
server {
        listen 1.2.3.4:80;
        server_name <имя_сайта_со_второго_сервера>;
        location / {
                    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:80/;
        }
}
```

[Документация](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) по модулю ngx_http_proxy_module, отвечающему за проксирование запросов.

Comment: Да впринципе я так и сделал. Но я подставил `server_name <ip_со_второго_сервера>;`
Если поставлю имя, то нужно поднимать dns на реальном сервере с зоной которая только отработает на локалхосте или же писать в hosts сервера. 
**Вопрос первый** такой если будет 2 или 3 сайта на втором сервере, будет работать? и 

` Получите заодно и плюшки в виде более быстрой обработки статики.`

**Вопрос второй:** Сможет ли обрабатывать статику со второго сервера?

Comment: @Viktor: ну если на втором сервере будет больше одного сайта, то их же понадобится как-то различать. Так что или на первом сервере понадобится больше внешних IP, что бы каждому сайту соответстовал свой IP, или им таки придётся дать имена. Обрабатывать статику на втором сервере - можно будет. Если на втором же сервере поставить nginx. Ну ещё можно nginx'ом внешнего сервера кешировать ответы от Apache на втором сервере, но это уже не то.

Comment: Тоесть, если у меня 1 внешний IP и домен site.com . то я смогу показать в инете все сайты которые будут на поддоменах(например a.site.com, b.site.com на одном сервере c внешним IP , а  c.site.com, d.site.com  на втором,  но уже на сером IP)?

Comment: @Viktor - да. Сайту и 4-м поддоменам даёте один IP - первого, внешнего сервера. На нём, в nginx'е, создаёте 4 блока `server`, с разными параметрами директивы `server_name`. Для основго сайта и поддоменов "a" и "b" - делаете обработку запросов на этом же сервере. Для осталных двух поддоменов пишите `proxy_pass` на IP второго сервера и добавляете `proxy_set_header Host $host;`, что бы передалось правильное имя сайта.

Comment: Тогда на втором сервере просто поднять апач с vhosts серым айпи и именами сайта? Не нужно на первом сервере поднимать DNS сервера для локалхоста чтобы правильно отображать сайт со второго сервера, достаточно proxy_set_header Host $host;?

Comment: @Viktor, нет, зачем там DNS сервер? У вас же домен этот уже на каких-то NS расположен? Для внешнего мира этого будет достаточно. А Apache'у на втором сервере вы передадите заголовок Host, он по своему конфигу разберётся из какого каталог файлы на  такой запрос показывать.